# How to get ID from Angular dropdown from value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As you can see in the code, I have a list cars Car A,B, and C with corresponding ids in availableCars list. I’m getting already chosen car from a service. It is not an object just the car name. User has option to choose different car but on change, I have to send car id to other service. Is there any simplest way to achieve my goal?

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    
    $scope.carName = (function getCarNameFromService(){
      return 'Car B';
    })();
    
    $scope.availableCars =  [
       {id: '1A', name: 'Car A'},
       {id: '2B', name: 'Car B'},
       {id: '3C', name: 'Car C'}
     ]
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ngrepeat-select-production</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="ngrepeatSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="repeatSelect"> Repeat select: </label>
    <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="carName">
      <option ng-repeat="option in availableCars" value="{{option.name}}">{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <tt>selected car name = {{carName}}</tt><br/>
   <tt>selected car id = ???</tt><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using an ng-repeat on the "option" element inside of a select, you can use "ng-options". [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

I created a [plnkr](https://plunker.co/edit/gW0MthQpx8) to illustrate your example. Some of the key pieces of code are as follows:

**JS**

```
  var carName = "Car B"; //name provided to this controller 

    $scope.availableCars =  [
       {id: '1A', name: 'Car A'},
       {id: '2B', name: 'Car B'},
       {id: '3C', name: 'Car C'}
     ]

     $scope.selectedCar = $scope.availableCars.filter(function(car){
         return car.name === carName;
     })[0];

    $scope.selectedId = $scope.selectedCar.id;

     $scope.updateCar = function(id){
         $scope.selectedId = id;
     }
```

and

**HTML**

```
<form name="myForm">
    <label for="repeatSelect"> Repeat select: </label>
    <select ng-options="car as car.name for car in availableCars" ng-model="selectedCar" ng-change="updateCar(selectedCar.id)"></select>
  </form>
```

Notice the "ng-change" and the "ng-options" in the html.

Comment: The problem is the model "selectedCar " can not be an object. I just have the name (in this case "Car B"). Also, the dropdown must have names. How can I make it work in this situation? thanks for your response.

Comment: I'm not sure why selectedCar can't be an object (if you are only getting name as input or something you could match the object in the list of available cars to get the correct one). Is there a specific reason why? I'll mess around with it and get back to you, but I don't think it's going to be to elegant of a solution if it's possible with ng-options.

Comment: I updated the plunker to do what you are asking, however it does continue to use the full car object as the driver for the dropdown (it first sets the default car by searching for it based on the name provided). Let me know if that doesn't work for what you are trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

> User has option to choose different car but on change, I have to send car id to other service

You could use `ng-change` for that:

```
<select ng-change="sendInfo(...)" ...>
...
</select>
```

Actually, I would advise to bind to the model the car id instead of the car name. Or a car object, providing you switch to `ng-options`. That way you could send the selected id.